# Encoding problem using Spring Boot and IBM DB2 in VSCode

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, jdbc, db2

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that interacts with a DB2 database. So far I was able to map entities, create repositories, and so on. Everything works fine.

The problem arises with registries inside the database which are somewhat encoded as (not sure) Unicode: when a special character is found, reading the value throws an exception.

Trying to identify this strange character using DBeaver lead to the same reading error.

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sqlexception-message-caught-javaiocharconversionexception-and-errorcode-4220), it's a known problem with the JDBC driver which can be bypassed using the guidelines given.

Now the real problem...

- In DBeaver, I was able to bypass the exception by adding the suggestion to `dbeaver.ini` file: the strange character is replaced by a **REPLACEMENT CHARACTER** (question mark inside a diamond), so the exception goes away.
- In VSCode, I tried almost everything to inform the needed Java arguments: `launch.json` (both **args** and **vmArgs** attributes), `settings.json`, `application.properties`... The most closely to working I could get is at `launch.json` (attribute **args**), as I could see that the argument is being passed to the Java executable (checking the console output), but even though the exception persists.

So the real question here is: how to avoid this exception? How can I actually make use of IBM DB2 guidelines inside this Spring Boot application?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Get the bad data in your database fixed, otherwise this problem will continue to cause trouble in future indefinitely until the bad data is either removed or fixed.

Comment: That's the perfect solution, indeed. But I don't have write access to the database, and there are plenty of registries with that problem. And even if I get write permissions, I would still need some batch processing mechanism to fix them all, as fixing individually in unpractical.

Comment: Just to note - I'm processing data using Kafka, and those problematic records are being registered in a separate topic. Original table has ~1.8mi records, and the problematic ones counts as 119 for now (25% of the processing done - it's not performance-optimized already).

Comment: It is not up to you to fix the data (unless it is your code that injected the bad data) . Instead, it is up to you to open a ticket with the data owner of that database, to point out that data corruption is present, and to point out the likely consequences of corrupt data not being removed or fixed with root cause found. In some cases, there are legal obligations to do the right thing.

Comment: You're right, it's not up to me to fix it, and wasn't my code the culprit. As a side note, data is not actually "corrupt": I verified some records using DBeaver (with the workaround from IBM) and it seems that some special characters are not being recognized. I identified some "É" characters missing from the output (presuming it from the whole word with the missing letter). It seems more like an encoding problem that the JDBC driver cannot handle well.

Comment: "special characters are not being recognized" because __they should not be there__ (i.e. the required codepage conversion was either not run, or the wrong conversion was run), caused by programming error or configuration error. The end result is the same, the data is corrupted.

Comment: I see your point now: a special character put in the string using the wrong encoding. That is a hell of a possibility, since I know the ones involved with the other side of the server :D

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me! I was hoping I could bypass this error using the suggestion from IBM, but I'm losing hope... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, you can add JVM arguments `"-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3"` by modifying the `vmArgs` attribute in your `launch.json` file.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Spring Boot App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.example.MyApplication",
            "projectName": "spring-project-name",
            "vmArgs": "-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace `com.example.MyApplication` with the main class of your Spring Boot application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said before, I tried that with no success. In "vmArgs" I don't even see this argument being passed to the Java executable. Putting it at "args" attribute sents it to the Java executable, but the setting is never used.